# Using ListView in Fragment not re-positioning

Tags: android, listview, fragment, adapter

I have an adapter which extends ArrayAdapter.
In my Fragment I create a listview that sets that adapter as the adapter.
However I can't reposition selected items to the top of the listview or remove selected items. Can someone please assist me.

My code for my Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatlist, container, false);
    chatListLV = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.chatLV);
    adapter = new ChatListAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.single_chatlist_row);
    chatListLV.setAdapter(adapter);
    chatListLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG,"You selected item at position " + position);
            ChatListDataProvider newChat = adapter.getItem(position);
            Log.d(TAG, "CHATLISTVIEW ON CLICK LISTENER");
            currentchat = newChat.roomID;
            int duration = 500; // miliseconds
            int offset = 0;
            chatListLV.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, offset, duration);
        }
    });
    return view;

}
```

Comment: Do you want the listview scroll to the top or item moved to the top of the listview? If second - you need to change the position of item in adapter and invoke adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Is there anyway I can change the position of the item in the adapter without first deleting it? @aelimill

Comment: Easy way - change the position in the collection of your extended Adapter

Comment: I'm sorry how would I go about that? What I was trying to do initially was that each time I would receive a new message, I would move that item to the top of the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke adapter.moveToTop(position) desired item.

public class ChatListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    public ChatListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Message object) {
        messages.add(object);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void addAll(Collection<? extends Message> collection) {
        messages.addAll(collection);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Message object) {
        messages.remove(object);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void moveToTop(int position) {
        Message item = getItem(position);

        remove(item);

        if (getCount() > 1) {
            messages.set(0,item);
        } else {
            messages.add(item);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Message getItem(int position) {
        return messages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }
}
```